# draw relative to camera position

Tags: c++, opengl

recently my boss told me to modify an opengl application.
It uses gluLookAt to set the camera position. 
I'd have to draw a toolbar relative to that position so that the user could always see it.

I'm almost a complete beginner in openGL, so I don't really know what would be easier, doing all the translations and rotations myself so I could draw the object in camera sight, or using the projection and view matrices? I managed to get the projection and view matrices with the glGetFloatv command, but to be honest, I have no idea how to use them to make the desired transformations. I could just use the basic translation and rotation commands, but I think using those matrices would be easier.

I would be gratefull for any answer :)

Comment: BTW- technicaly, you don't want to draw "relative to camera position". You want to do the opposite: draw on the same place of the screen regardless of where the camera is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What might be easier instead is to change the projection and modelview matrices after drawing the 3D scene. Change the projection matrix to a glOrtho2D, and the modelview so that it scales to fit the screen and then draw the toolbar. See the answers here for specifics:

[Opengl drawing a 2d overlay on a 3d scene problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4280185/opengl-drawing-a-2d-overlay-on-a-3d-scene-problem)

Comment: Thx :), that's what I needed. I also had some success using the glLoadIdentity command. All I had to do is push the current matrix to the stack, load the identity matrix, perform some transformations, drawing something and then loading the original matrix from stack. I don't know if it's a good solution, will continue searching.