# 2D overlay over 3D scene not working

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I am attempting to create a 2D overlay over a 3D scene! I have tried all the solutions I can find on GameDev and StackOverflow, however they have not seemed to work!

My current code:

```
static void ready3D()
{
    glViewport(0, 0, Display.getWidth(),Display.getHeight());
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);

    glLoadIdentity();
    GLU.gluPerspective(45, (float) Display.getWidth()/Display.getHeight(), 0.1f, 5000.0f);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
}

static void ready2D()
{
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    GLU.gluOrtho2D(0.0f, Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight(), 0.0f);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(0.375f, 0.375f, 0.0f);

    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
}
```

And,

```
glPushMatrix();
    //Overlay start - This is in my render method BTW.
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    ready2D();

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glColor3f(1, 1, 1);
    glVertex2f(0, 0); // bottom-left
            glVertex2f(0, 1); // top-left
            glVertex2f(1, 1); // top-right
            glVertex2f(1, 0); // bottom-right
    glEnd();

    glPopMatrix();
    ready3D();
```

However the 2D box thing that I am trying to draw does not draw! Obviously I eventually hope to have complicated objects/icons on an overlay, but first things first.

The 3D world still draws totally fine.

Is anyone able to tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What's the purpose of the `glTranslate` in your `ready2D` method? Is it just to move the quad?  Have you tried removing that?

Comment: @stridecolossus I do not know what it is, however I was given that method in OpenGL and had to modify it to LWJGL, and decided that whoever wrote it probably knew better than me.
I tried removing the line, and I still could not see the square.

Comment: I think your are drawing a single pixel. The gluOrtho2D call define your screen scale (very simplified...) and you have to specify your vertex in that scale. I mean, try glVertex2f(0, 100) and so on.

Comment: @stridecolossus: That is a sub-pixel offset, its real purpose is to make primitives like lines, points and triangles as well as raster positions (e.g. `glRasterPos2i (...)`) all align to the same pixel during rasterization. They use different rules regarding sample coverage (e.g. whether a pixel is considered covered if the ***center*** of it is covered or the top-left corner), but that 0.375 trick makes them more or less uniform. It is not particularly useful unless you are trying to do "pixel-perfect" rendering, but it does not hurt anything either...

Answer (score 0):

The order of the vertices in the 2D quad look a bit suspicious to me, if I'm reading that rightly it's going: bottom-left, top-right, bottom-right, top-left, which results in a sort of cross rather than a quad.

Try this:

```
glVertex2f(0, 0); // bottom-left
glVertex2f(0, 1); // top-left
glVertex2f(1, 1); // top-right
glVertex2f(1, 0); // bottom-right
```

Note the clockwise ordering which I believe OpenGL is expecting by default for front-facing quads.

Comment: Thank you. I am always forgetting that, even though I have done LWJGL for almost 2 years!
However, it has not solved my problem. It is still not showing the square.

Comment: Related thread that might have some other 'angles' for you to try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4280185/opengl-drawing-a-2d-overlay-on-a-3d-scene-problem?rq=1