# OpenGL - incorrect drawing of 2D overlay on top of 3D Scene

Tags: c++, opengl, orthographic

I am trying to draw a 2D overlay on top of a 3D model where it must appear on the left corner of the screen but what I get is a the rectangle which I am trying to draw is placed in the middle of the 3D model. You can see below for the screenshot of my output.
[image]

My setup for the orthogonal matrix is like this

```
2 / (right - left), 0, 0, 0,
0, 2 / (top - bottom), 0, 0,
0, 0, 2 / (far - near), 0,
-(right + left) / (right - left), -(top + bottom) / (top - bottom), -(far + near) / (far - near), 1
```

For the steps on how do I draw a 2D overlay on top of 3D, I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4281212/3867911) answer. Also it looks like the rectangle is not an overlay at all based on the output.
Hope you can help me :)

EDIT :

This is how I draw the model. Notice that this block of code will be used twice to draw 2 models

```
GLuint vao;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
glBindVertexArray(vao);

GLuint buffer;
glGenBuffers(1, &buffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cc * sizeof(GLfloat), v, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

GLuint tcbuffer;
glGenBuffers(1, &tcbuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, tcbuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, tcc * sizeof(GLfloat), vt, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

GLuint ncbuffer;
glGenBuffers(1, &ncbuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, ncbuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, ncc * sizeof(GLfloat), vn, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(m_vert);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbufferid);
glVertexAttribPointer(m_vert, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(m_texcoord);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, tcbufferid);
glVertexAttribPointer(m_texcoord, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(m_color);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cbufferid);
glVertexAttribPointer(m_color, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(m_vertexnormal);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, ncbufferid);
glVertexAttribPointer(m_vertexnormal, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vc);
```

And for the setup of the projections.

```
Matrix44 fov_matrix(double fov, double aspect, double near, double far) {
    var yScale = 1.0 / Math.tan(fov / 2);
    var xScale = yScale / aspect;
    return(Matrix44.for_values(
        xScale, 0, 0, 0,
        0, yScale, 0, 0,
        0, 0, (far + near) / (near - far), -1,
        0, 0, 2 * far * near / (near - far), 0
    ));
}

Matrix44 orthographic_matrix(double left, double right, double bottom, double top, double near, double far) {
    return(Matrix44.for_values(
        2 / (right - left), 0, 0, 0,
        0, 2 / (top - bottom), 0, 0,
        0, 0, 2 / (far - near), 0,
        -(right + left) / (right - left), -(top + bottom) / (top - bottom), -(far + near) / (far - near), 1
    ));
}

var projm = fov_matrix(MathConstant.M_PI/4, get_aspect_ratio(), 1.0, 100.0);
var orthoprojm = orthographic_matrix(0.0, 800, 600, 0.0, -100.0, 1.0);
```

Comment: Just draw the 3D scene then afterward draw the interface without matrix transformations relative to the camera. We need to see more code to really know what's going wrong.

Comment: Also, is old-opengl concrete? or can you switch to *at least* 2.1 and shaders?

Comment: @CoffeeandCode - I have edited my post above. Please see the additional information.

Comment: That snippet does not look like C++

Comment: Are you using shaders?

Comment: @CoffeeandCode - Yes except for the drawing of the model.

Comment: @ivaigult - Of course I am using shaders

Comment: @zyneragetro "of course" The answer you linked to was using old-style non-shader based opengl.

Comment: You're making things much more difficult than necessary. If you want to draw geometry without transforming it, simply use a shader that does not apply transformations.

Comment: @RetoKoradi - How can I switch between 2 shaders during runtime?

Comment: @zyneragetro Call `glUseProgram()` with a different shader program.

Comment: @RetoKoradi - This solves my problem and achieve the output I expect. Thank you :)

Comment: @RetoKoradi - I just noticed with this that instead of the output placed in top-left corner which is the origin of a 2d scene, the triangle is placed in the middle. It seems like it is still in a 3d world

Comment: @zyneragetro The origin of the native OpenGL coordinate system (NDC = normalized device coordinates) is in the center of the window. If you want to use coordinates relative to another origin, you'll need to apply an offset.

Comment: @RetoKoradi - How can I apply an offset? Sorry but I have no idea what offset is in opengl

Answer (score 2):

Your projection matricies looks correct to me. Looks like matrices that were used for Spanch Bob drawing were used for your overlay too. 
Check:

1. Both shaders for overlay are compiled. `glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status);`
2. Overlay program is properly linked. `glGetProgramiv(program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &status);`
3. Check that you are using correct program. `glGetIntegeriv(GL_CURRENT_PROGRAM, &program)`
4. `glGetUniformLocation(program, "yourMVPmatrix")` returns correct id.

Note, that if any program was not properly linked OpenGL won't race error on any of `glDraw*`.

Comment: Just a clarification for point one, will there be a different shader for the overlay ? Currently I am just using the shader used for the 3d model.

Comment: Well, then you should you `glUniform*` to update your MVP matrix at least. (I don't see such a call in your listings)

Comment: I am using glUniform to update the MVP matrix but for now I simplified things by using a different shader.